# Log4jConfigurer Alternative

Tags: log4j

I see that the class `org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer` is deprecated, but I could not find which class should be used as a replacement.
Specifically, I need `Log4jConfigurer.initLogging`.

Does anybody know which class/method I should use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only needed for non-default log4j initialization, for example with a custom config location or a refresh interval. By default, log4j will simply read its configuration from a `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file in the root of the classpath.

```
String prop = System.getProperty("log4j.configuration");
if (prop == null) prop = "log4j.properties";
URL log4jConfig = Loader.getResource(prop);
if (log4jConfig.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("file")){
    PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfig.getFile().substring(1), 10000);
}else{
    // cannot monitor if file changed because URL is not a file
}
```

Check [this link.](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html)

Comment: I know. I need the non-default initialization.